# How can I make to throw this catch with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, jira

I got a function that make an update of an issue in jira and i want to throw the catch using JUnit.

This is the function that I got:

```java
@PutMapping (value = "/update/{issueKey}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO>
           updateIssue(@Validated @RequestBody EventDTO eventDTO, BindingResult result, @PathVariable String issueKey)
    {
        logger.info("Entra en /update con el payload: {}", eventDTO);

        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = ErrorResponseDTO.getErrorResponseDTOFromBinding(result, messageSource);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        try
        {
            SuccessResponseDTO successResponseDTO = jiraService.update(eventDTO, issueKey);
            logger.info("/update response {} ", successResponseDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(successResponseDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (EywaException eywaException)
        {
            logger.error("Se ha producido un error en actualizar un issue", eywaException);
            ErrorResponseDTO responseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();


            String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(eywaException.getMessage(), null,
                    LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
            responseDTO.addErrorResponseDTO(eywaException.getMessage().split("\\.")[0], errorMessage);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is what i have in the JUnit

```
@Test
    public void updateIssue_NonExistanceIssue_shouldReturnFail() throws Exception
    {
        when(jiraService.update(eventDTO, "")).thenReturn(successResponseDTO);

        String json = "{\"summary\":\""+eventDTO.getSummary()+"\""+
                ", \"description\":\""+eventDTO.getDescription()+"\""+
                ", \"raised\":\""+eventDTO.getRaised()+"\""+
                ", \"issueType\":\""+eventDTO.getIssueType()+"\""+
                ", \"priority\":\""+eventDTO.getPriority()+"\""+
                ", \"issuesubType\":\""+eventDTO.getIssuesubType()+"\""+
                ", \"region\":\""+eventDTO.getRegion()+"\""+
                ", \"airport\":\""+eventDTO.getAirport()+"\""+"}";

        mvc.perform(put(BASE + UPDATE.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}", ""))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());

    }
```

(I have already created the object in the setup)
The status i'm getting is the 405 and when i put an issueKey i got the status 200 (even when the issue key don't exist)

It has to throw status 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the JUnit test you have to make `.thenThrow(eywaException);` instead of the `.thenReturn(successResponseDTO);` to make the test go through the exception and get the 500 status

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the path variable.
The end point is "/update/{issueKey}" but during the test you call the "/update/" (?).

The Spring  knows the first end-point, you call the second and spring cant find this end-point and throws 405 Method Not Allowed (You don't have PUT /update).

Comment: I have tried to put the issue key before and i don't get the 500, sorry for not mentioning this in the post

Comment: try remove the BASE variable from put(..)
The spring calls it internally.

(The base is you ip/localhost?)

Comment: BASE + UPDATE is the direction that im sending, i have already remove it and now i got the 404

Comment: have you also just removed the BASE part? because 405 normally means that the method was not found

Comment: if you can give us your BASE content and UPDATE content.

Also, your controller has base url (RequestMapping("/something/")

Try a test with string, for example mvc.perform(put("/update/SOMEID")) or mvc.perform(put("/something/update/SOMEID"))

Comment: for sure, these are my values:
public static final String BASE = "/test/v1/issue";
public static final String UPDATE = "/update/{issueKey}";

Comment: at the setup (that is executed before the test) i got also this: successResponseDTO = new SuccessResponseDTO(1L, "key", new URI("http://localhost:8080/1"));